# issues in writing xml files in php

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I wrote a code in which i m writing new xml files depending on content of one xml file i have with me right now.
In xml file from which i m reading,there are 14 fragments with 3 -4 nodes each.I have to right 7 new xml files in this case,each containing 2 fragments from first file.
So that all xml files after writing should have 2 fragments each,totalling all to 14 fragments when all files combined.

But the code is not giving me the correct output

following is the code

```
<?php
$docOutput  = new DOMDocument("1.0");

$root = $docOutput ->createElement("data");
$docOutput ->appendChild($root);
if(!$xml=simplexml_load_file('xmlfile.xml')){
trigger_error('Error reading XML file',E_USER_ERROR);
}
$array1=array();
$x=0;
foreach($xml as $syn)
{

for($i=$x*2;$i<($x+1)*2;$i++)
{
//$array1[] = $syn->productId;
echo $i;
echo "<br />";
echo $syn->productId;
$id   = $docOutput ->createElement("PID");
$idText = $docOutput ->createTextNode($syn->productId);
$id->appendChild($idText);

$title   = $docOutput ->createElement("PNAME");
$titleText = $docOutput ->createTextNode($syn->productname);
$title->appendChild($titleText);


$book = $docOutput ->createElement("Product");
$book->appendChild($id);
$book->appendChild($title);

$root->appendChild($book);


}
$docOutput ->formatOutput = true;
echo "<xmp>". $docOutput ->saveXML() ."</xmp>";

$docOutput ->save("mybooks$x.xml") or die("Error");

$x++;

}
//echo count($array1, COUNT_RECURSIVE);
?>
```

Following is one fragment of file,which i m reading

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<data>
  <Product>
    <PID>SGLDN7XJ2FPZH8G8</PID>
    <PNAME>Miami Blues Aviator Sunglasses</PNAME>
  </Product>
</data>
```

There are 14 Product fragments in file from which i m reading.After writing i should get 7 files with two fragments each.

Please help in correcting the code

Comment: could you add what your code currently returns ?

Comment: it return with 14 new files,but the product fragements in each files are increasing by 2,like first file will have 2 fragments,second one will have 4,so on till the end and last one will have 28 fragments,which is wrong,where as every file should only have 2 fragments

Comment: your issue is the inner loop `for($i=$x*2;$i<($x+1)*2;$i++)` that's just wrong as you tell to do exactly that way as you can see in your output. It's easier to just use one loop, here the outer `foreach`. See as well my answer which shows exactly that.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you've got is less with the code to read/write the XML but more just with the basic looping logic.

What you perhaps actually want is while iterating over the product nodes, to move the iteration ahead so you can put two product elements together. This works with a **SimpleXMLIterator**:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($buffer, 'SimpleXMLIterator');

foreach ($xml as $product) {

    // output current element
    printf("-+-%s\n", $product->asXML());

    // move to next element
    $xml->next();
    $product = $xml->current();

    // output next element
    printf(" \- %s\n\n", $product->asXML());
}
```

With this XML input:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<data>
  <Product>1</Product>
  <Product>2</Product>
  <Product>3</Product>
  <Product>4</Product>
</data>
```

The example outputs:

```
-+-<Product>1</Product>
 \- <Product>2</Product>

-+-<Product>3</Product>
 \- <Product>4</Product>
```

Online-Demo: https://eval.in/172918

Comment: No but how can i write them in different files with 2-2 fragments each sir.Please guide on that

Comment: Yes, yes yes! In exactly that manner, sir! 2-2 fragment are each there in the listing. Open your eyes and stare at the output! Alternative encapsulate the pagination (pairing) in an iterator of it's own with the help of for example **LimitIterator** you have in SPL.

Comment: I m asking about saving them in different xml files.here i can just print them,which i can see.

Comment: yes sure, because this shows how to get data. the way you save is perfectly okay, just replace the print here with the way you save in your question. I thought that was obvious by the introductory sentence. Your code to save XML file is pretty much fine, it needs no changes. You just have problem in the logic to get the elements you want to save. This shown in the answer.

Comment: Also here another hint: Properly indent the code in your question. That should make it more clear to you. Also you should post self-containing examples. So better not paste your development code, but for the question, create a new example from scratch that just demonstrates with as little data and code as necessary your issue. That will not only give you more understanding about what you do but it will also make the question more useful for future visitors.